# Script copies row data to another sheet, is only partially working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to move a row of data in an employee schedule  spreadsheet (thanks to help from the Sheets reddit) it is working but has stopped finding one part of the data.

Spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10yLJ_NyFasGhlRt2LsXO2CC804Zf5JLvwUisgytQOhM/edit?usp=sharing

Once the Finished column 63 is set to "YES" it copies the data (only from the required columns), locates the employee's name based on whose week is marked "x" and moves them to the Finished Sheet.

The code used to work fully but now it isn't finding "x" or grabbing the employee's name. 
I've had to update the column numbers in the script a few times as we've gotten more employees, it's possible I've broken it doing that.

(Any blank columns do have data in my real spreadsheet I've just left them blank here as it's not relevant to the script)

Would really appreciate any advice! Thank you!

[Full code in spreadsheet]

```
  if (ecol == 63 && ssh.getName() == 'SCHEDULE' && rng.getValue() == 'YES') { //if Schedule!63 is YES
    var data = []; //output data
    var rowN = rng.getRow();
    var rowV = ssh.getRange(rowN,1,1,63).getDisplayValues();
    var row = rowV[0]; //get edited row
    var colX = row.indexOf('x')+1; //find X
    var offset = colX - ((colX-2) % 5 ) // offset to the first column 
    var emp = ssh.getRange(1,offset).getValue(); //get employee name
    var dd = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+10", "dd/MM/yyyy") //generate date finished
    data.push(row[1],row[2],row[3],dd,row[5],emp); //get row
    dsh.appendRow(data); //move row
    ssh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart); //delete from schedule
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the number of the last column now?

Comment: It's column BK, so that should be 63

Comment: Have you added any columns to the left of the employee columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this `var offset = colX - ((colX-2) % 5 ) // offset to the first column`

should be this `var offset = colX - ((colX+2) % 5 ) // offset to the first column`

This is what's causing you to not find employees because the employees are in a merge group of cells which always puts it's value in the left most cell for horizontal merging.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! Unfortunately when I change -2 to +2 the code no longer works at all. 
The cells on the employee names aren't merged just set to text overflow

Comment: Okay. But the employee names only exist in the first cell of each group on row 1.

Comment: Why are those x's in the first column there and why can't I delete them.

Comment: oh, yes true! and the X's in the far left column are from an arrayformula in cell A3.

Comment: Well I think that's what's messing up your ability to find employees because the `row.indexOf('x')` always returns 1.

Comment: It's supposed to be `var offset = colX - ((colX+2) % 5 )` .  Was that array formula added recently?  Because it's messing up the operation of the onEdit()

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you so much. I've changed the arrayformula to use a different character, changed the colX and it's working now. 
thanks again

Comment: I saved that array formula in Sheet3 if you need it

Comment: We're you able to see how I was debugging the onEdit() using `e.source.toast();` as sort of a console.log